# Google appengine cloud storage free quota

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Following page says that first 5 GB of google cloud storage is free.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=en

But, to access cloud storage, I need to sign up for a free trial. (When I access cloud storage tab in developer console, it tells me to register for a free trial)

So, even when first 5 GB is anyway free, why do I need to register for a free trial?

This trial is for 60 days. So, if I register for the trial, when 60 days elapsed, will access to cloud storage get blocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free trial is actually a $300 credit, so you can go over the 5G until that credit runs out or the trial duration ends.

When the trial ends and you're under 5G you're OK. If you're over 5G you'll be charged for what's over the 5G.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the Cloud Storage default bucket, where you will have a [free default limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Default_Gcs_Bucket) of 5 GB.

If you access it programmatically, there is no need to sign up for Free Trial. The default bucket name is typically app_id.appspot.com, where app_id is your application ID. You will need to sign up if you try accessing it via UI.

You can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/activate#Using_a_default_bucket) a brief description on how to activate and to start using the default bucket.